# Activating PS4s as primary

Tags: ps4

I gameshared with my friend and it worked however, him and I wanna play the same game together online. I want to use my account which is the one I used to gameshare with him, and he wants to use his own account that he downloaded the game I shared with him and I know that him or I have to activate the account as primary for the PS4 system in order to play the game.

My question is, can we both activate the same account as primary and play the same game simultaneously?

Comment: Don't have a PS4, but I'd expect only the account, which owns the game can be used as primary. Your friend downloaded the game via gameshare and can play it as a secondary, but as his account doesn't own the game, he can never be a primary.

Comment: I’m not talking about shareplay, i’m talking about gameshare which means sharing my account with him and him sharing it with me if wanted to, And my question is can we both play the same game at the same time and by that i mean how to unlock the game for both of us at the same time(Activating PS4 account as primary) in more than 1 PS4 system

Answer (score 1):

On the official page they specifically state you can play multiplayer on local but not online: https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/explore/ps4/features/share-play/

Answer (score 0):

Only one PS4 can be activated as primary for any particular account.  A game can be played on any system that is logged in to that account (primary or not) or is activated for that account (with any account signed in.)

For instance, my son and I have played Overwatch together using my purchase.  The PS4 in the living room is activated for my account.  He signs in to that PS4 with his account.  I sign in to a PS4 in the den with my account.  We can then play together, online.

Note that anyone who has access to a PS4 your account is activated as primary on has a large amount of access to that account...it is not something you should do if you don't absolutely trust that person.

Answer (score 0):

In order to play a game on an account other than the owner, the console needs to be activated as Primary for the owner account. One one console can be activated as primary per one account.

In you case, you play with your own, owner, account, so you don't need your console to be activated as primary; your friend's console does.

After you do this both of you could play the same game at the same time, but on your account must be signed in at all times to access its games.